# how to disable reaching ajax call from browser

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have following ajax call

```
open: function () {
                     $(this).load("MyBox.aspx?sec=L&levId=" + RowId);
                 }
```

so people can see the querystring, so the user can copy url and paste it to browser but how can i block that? I dont want it to shown from browser. How I can do that? I m using asp.net and jquery.

Comment: Your request uses `GET` method, Use `POST` method. http://api.jquery.com/load/#request-method

Answer (score 2):

`load` function issues a **GET** request. Instead of that, you may use a jQuery **POST** call and get the data. Users can't get the result by pasting it in browser and hit enter (which is GET request)

```
  var thatObject=$(this);
  $.post("MyBox.aspx?sec=L&levId=" + RowId,function(response){
     thatObject.html(response);
  })
```

In the server page, you can read the values posted by checking the **Request.Form** collection (instead of Request.QueryString).

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> The Form collection retrieves the values of form elements posted to
>   the HTTP request body, with a form using the POST method.

You can determine whether the call is a GET call or POST call by inspecting the [`Request.RequestType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.requesttype.aspx) property value. This way you can avoid people issuing GET request to this method and getting the response.

But remember that, there are tools/browser addons which does the POST request from browser.

Also if the data is for authorized users, you may check the user is authorized to access it in  the server page(MYbox.aspx) before returning the content.

Comment: ok i change it to post but when i past it (http://mysite.com/MyBox.aspx?sec=L&levId= +"2") to browser i can see the page contents

Comment: @MichaelRiva: Use HttpRequest.RequestType Property to determine whether it is a GET / POST. check my updated answer.

Comment: hmm thanks a lot, how can i check user is authorized to access?

Comment: @MichaelRiva that depends on you app. may be session

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  You can never trust any code running on the client.  If you need to hide data on the client, you should create a server based session and then put a session token in an encrypted cookie.

Comment: so if i create session same user still can see the content by pasting the url another browse? can you tell me any tutorial for this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia and W3C

> Some methods (for example, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS and TRACE) are defined as safe, which means they are intended only for information retrieval **and should not change the state of the server**. In other words, they should not have side effects, beyond relatively harmless effects such as logging, caching, the serving of banner advertisements or incrementing a web counter. 
>   Making arbitrary GET requests without regard to the context of the application's state should therefore be considered safe.
>
> By contrast, methods such as POST, PUT and DELETE are intended for actions that may cause side effect

If your get request changes the state of the server (which it most likely does based on your post), you are doing something wrong. What you're trying to do is impossible. You need to rethink your architecture.